# What is the procedure to build the libjingle_peerconnection_so.so library for different platform?

Tags: webrtc, libjingle

I'm getting the webrtc android(binary) artefacts from [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.pristine/libjingle). I made some changes in webrtc source code. Now I want to build my own  libjingle_peerconnection_so.so  binary. What is the procedure to build the binary files for different platform. Please suggest any solution or links to refer. I tried and got the solution for build the .APK file. But it is difficult to get the procedure to build the binary file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the procedure to how build the libjingle_peerconnection_so.so library and libjingle_peerconnection_java.jar.

First pull all the files. Follow the [link](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/) to do.
set the os and architechture

```
export GYP_DEFINES="$GYP_DEFINES OS=android target_arch=armv7"
```

Then run the following ninja file from `src/out/Debug/obj/webrtc/api` directory,

```
ninja -C out/debug libjingle_peerconnection_so.ninja
```

It will generate specific .so file for mentioned architecture in `GYP_DEFINES`